# Mautic API error 404: Requested URL not found: /api/contacts

Tags: symfony, bitnami, mautic

I followed the steps exactly as I am supposed to

- Install VirtualBox on Windows 10
- Download and install the OVA format of Bitnami Virtualbox from [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/mautic/virtual-machine)
- I tried both 4.0.1-6 and 3.3.3-19 and it gives the same error
- I can access the VirtualBox instance from my Mac and login remotely
- I enabled API access
- The moment I try to retrieve the /api/contacts, it immediately gives me a 404 error

Tried following the guide [HERE](https://forum.mautic.org/t/mautic-api-error-requested-url-not-found/7227/3) that is asking me to clear the cache
Tried running the commands [HERE](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/apps/mautic/administration/clean-cache/) to clear the mautic cache
It gives me Segmentation Fault on both versions and cache clear fails
[image]

When I try to clear the cache it is now giving me an error and without clearing the cache the API is not working
Really appreciate if someone can tell me what is happening

Comment: Version 3.3.3 works! and 4.0.1-6 has Segmentation Fault

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, did you try increasing the memory_limit value in the /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini file. Please note that the solution is configured with a predefined value and those commands might need more memory to run properly. You can also try increasing the resources of the VM (increasing the available RAM memory for example) in case the new memory_limit value doesn't make any change.

Comment: @JotaMartos it works after increasing the memory, default memory is 256M, how much should it be increased to if you have a 1GB instance? is it safe to set it to 1GB? thank you

Comment: you shouldn't increase the memory to 1GB if the machine has 1GB because the machine will run out of memory if PHP starts using the whole available memory. If you want to set the memory_limit to 1GB, you will need to increase the machine's memory to 1.5 or 2 GB